# Error Error: Invalid child of messaging:emailTemplate. Only messaging components are allowed as children of messaging:emailTemplate

Tags: visualforce, vf-email-template

I am facing the below error while creating the VisualForce Email Template.

Why?

**Error**

> Error Error: Invalid child of messaging:emailTemplate. Only messaging components are allowed as children of messaging:emailTemplate.

**Template**

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Legal Case" recipientType="User" >
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody >

    /*<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
        Congratulations!
        This is your new Visualforce Email Template.
    </messaging:plainTextEmailBody> */
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is occurring because you are commenting your code like apex class with "/**/" sign.

As it Visualforce email template it should be commented like visual force page like below : -

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Legal Case" recipientType="User" >
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody >

<!--<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
Congratulations!
This is your new Visualforce Email Template.
</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>-->
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

then it will be working.In my DE it is working.